# Locate installation folder for opencv3 (or any opencv for that matter) when installing through pip package manager

Tags: python, opencv, pip, locate

i've installed opencv through pip install, and not through the tedious process of make install builds. But this method is somehow not enabling me to find where it installed my cv2 pakages. Is it a thing with the pip? Conventionally I should have opencv folder in my /usr/include/ . But where do I find it if I installed in this manner. I need those especially to access the sample files that we need at times. Other than that the installation has done a pretty good jog and all the programs work just fine. Thank you

Comment: `python_install_dir/Lib/site-packages`

Comment: otherwise, just evaluate the package (or `print(cv2)`) and you'll get the filename back…

Comment: `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__file__); print(cv2.__path__)"`

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. The print(cv2) and the similar options worked to get me the location of the cv.so file and could figure out the location of other cv2 related documents as well. Hidden files are involved which made it less apparent in the beginning. Thank you. Although the example files are still seem to be hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your questions and comments, I think you want to:

> Q(1) Locate where the `cv2` is installed;

```
import cv2 
print(cv2)
print(cv2.__file__)
```

This is on my machine:

Windows: `site-packages\\cv2\\cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`

Linux: `site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

> Q(2) Locate the opencv example files

If you install OpenCV from pip or so, then you mostly havn't install the OpenCV example files, except some data files( such as haarcascade_eye.xml, haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml ...).

A generaly way to get the sample files is to go to github and download the release codes

[OpenCV Release](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases) | [OpenCV Contrib release](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases)

Or just read online:

[OpenCV cpp|python|java samples ...](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples)

---

Links:

1. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases
2. https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases
3. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples